# Function not able to get the latest state value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I am new to react state hook. Here is the sample code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export function App(props) {
  const [c, setC] = useState(0);
  const [b1, setB1] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setC(1);
    let b1 = document.getElementById("b1");
    b1.addEventListener("click", f1);
    setB1(b1);
  }, []);

  const f1 = () => {
    console.log(c);
  }

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>Hello React.</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button id="b1" />
    </div>
  );
}

// Log to console
console.log('Hello console')
```

If I click the button. The console always output 0 instead of 1 where i set the value in useEffect.

Please let me know what's wrong here. Looks like when I add eventlistener on the button, it remembers the C value instead of reading the C value from state every time.

Comment: Why don't you attach the event listener to the button directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time that the click listener is attached, the render that the state value closes over is that when the `useEffect` callback was declared - which is when `c` was still the prior value from back then. While you could fix it by logging `c + 1`, a much better approach would be to avoid vanilla DOM methods entirely in React, and do it the React way instead, with a JSX `onClick` prop on the button.

```js
const App = () => {
  const [c, setC] = React.useState(0);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setC(1);
  }, []);
  const f1 = () => {
    console.log(c);
  }
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>Hello React.</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button onClick={f1}>click</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('.react')).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```